# How to properly set up node js rest api

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, socks

Im a android dev and trying to make a simple rest api with node js, so Im basically new to js.
Im setting up a new rest api and want to connect to mysql database. 
I was trying to solve that this way, but I'm getting errors.

And, also how many connection limits to set ?

```
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../db');

    const mainNewsRouter = express.Router();

    mainNewsRouter.get('/', async (req, res, next) => {
        try {
          let result = await db.getMainNews();
          console.log(res.json(result));
          res.json(result);
        } catch(e) {
          console.log(e);
        }
    });

    module.exports = mainNewsRouter;

    //DbHandler.js

    var mysql = require('mysql2');
    const url = require('url');
    var SocksConnection = require('socksjs');

    var remote_options = {
        host:'xxx',
        port: 3306
    };

    var proxy = url.parse('http://xxx:xxx@us-east-static-06.quotaguard.com:xxx');
    var auth = proxy.auth;
    var username = auth.split(":")[0];
    var pass = auth.split(":")[1];

    var sock_options = {
    host: proxy.hostname,
    port: 1080,
    user: username,
    pass: pass
    };

    var sockConn = new SocksConnection(remote_options, sock_options);
    var dbConnection = mysql.createPool({
        connectionLimit: 10,
        user: 'xxx',
        database: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx',
        stream: sockConn
    });


    getMainNews = () => {

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          dbConnection.query('SELECT ... * from ...;',
         (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              return reject(err);
            };

    //          sockConn.dispose();
              return resolve(results);
          });
      });

      dbConnection.end();
    };

On first api call I get data from database, but with this error:

Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (node_modules\express\lib\response.js:771:10)
    at ServerResponse.send (node_modules\express\lib\response.js:170:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (node_modules\express\lib\response.js:267:15)
    at mainNewsRouter.get (server\routes\mainNews.js:10:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

And after second API call there is no data, I only get this exception.

```
> Server is running on port: { Error: This socket has been ended by the
> other party
>     at Socket.writeAfterFIN [as write] (net.js:395:12)
>     at SocksConnection._write (node_modules\socksjs\socks.js:72:24)
>     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:415:12)
>     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:399:5)
>     at SocksConnection.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:299:11)
>     at PoolConnection.write (node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:221:17)
>     at PoolConnection.writePacket(node_modules\mysql2\lib\connection.js:279:12)
>     at ClientHandshake.sendCredentials (node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\client_handshake.js:63:16)
>     at ClientHandshake.handshakeInit (node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\client_handshake.js:136:12)
>     at ClientHandshake.execute (node_modules\mysql2\lib\commands\command.js:39:22) code: 'EPIPE',
> fatal: true }
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am by no means an expert, I think one of the issues lies with closing the connection. The whole idea of a pool is to release the connection back to the pool, not close it.

I have done testing on connection pools and have used a pool size of min:4 max:12 with 100s of requests per second without running into connections issues with MySQL.

Personally, I use Knex to manage my db connections, it manages all of the pools too, taking care of a lot of the headache. Low overhead, I think it would be worth porting over that part of your code to. Once the connection issue is sorted out, then you could tackle other issues as they crop up.

Again, I am not an expert and cannot exactly nail down releasing the MySQL connection back to the pool in the code above, but I do think that is why you don't get data after your initial call.

Answer (score 0):

It wont answer your full question but still. The "Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client" means that a header has already been set but the user is again trying to set it. A header is set when we send a response. Headers include the content type, content-length,status and all the information about the response we are sending. When we write res.send or res.json or res.render i.e sending a response the headers get set automatically using the required information (Express does it automatically for us, in pure nodejs we have to set every header by ourselves). Notice that you have written res.json two times which means it has to set the headers twice. Also writing res.json inside console.log doesnt make any sense. Why have you done that?